# Why does S3 file get a prefix after upload?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fetch, aws-sdk

StackOverflow

I'm putting an object to S3 directly from the browser via a signedUrl.

The code I'm using looks roughly like this:

```js
const formData = new FormData()
const file = await selectorToInput.files[0]

formData.append('file', file)

await fetch(uploadUrl, {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: formData,
  mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/yaml',
    }
}).then(r => r.ok)
```

The upload is successful, however, when retrieving the objects after they've been uploaded they're all prefixed with characters like this:

```
-----------------------------3536405376111676041452100156
'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

<THE REST OF THE FILE CONTENTS>
```

They look like file headers of some kind, but can't figure out for the life of me where they're coming from. For more context, these files are all `yaml` and these additional characters are causing the parser I'm using to throw malformed yaml errors, so I don't feel like they're suppose to be there.

I've also tried this without using the `.text()` call on the `File` object and get the same result with different looking headers. Is this an issue/feature of `Fetch`?

I wish I could provide more info, but I've been searching for several hours now and haven't found an explanation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own issue here. After more digging I found [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/558#issuecomment-89385027) on the amazon sdk. Turns out that wrapping the file in `FormData` was the issue. This goes contrary to all other documentation I found, so hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: There are multiple ways to upload to S3.  If you want to use the form post, you need to include the appropriate fields.  You can do a normal HTTP PUT with the Fetch API, just without the form data, as you've found.  (The form post for S3 is an old API... 2006 or so, well before the Fetch API existed, and before there was a solid consensus on how XHR was supposed to work.)

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense now that I've found the answer. I don't want to aws-sdk to be in the UI at all so the HTTP PUT was the way to go. I wish I would have found in the docs somewhere that this was a potential problem. Oh well ‍♂️ you live and you learn.